# Add Generic Type to Component in vue.js with Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Component in Vue which has a specific set of data. The data is always defined by an Interface in typescript. At this moment, I keep the info about the selected items out of the DataTable Component because I'm using the interface to check the data types.

What I want is a way to give an interface to the DataTable, so the DataTable itself can be responsible for the selected data in its own Component. I use class-style components, so something like `export default class DataTable<T extends object> extends Vue {}` would be perfect. This is not a problem, but I can't seem to find a way to implement the component in another component AND giving it the needed generic type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any progress with this?